# Python String to ASCII and back

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, encryption, ascii

I need to turn an entered string into ASCII values, add three to them, then print out the new string that got all the letters changed.

I got to the point where I can get the ASCII values in a list, but i'm having trouble turning that back into a string.

This is the code I wrote so far.

```
def encrypt (x):  #function for encrypting
#y=[ord(c) for c in x] #turns strings into values this works
#y=[3+ ord(c) for c in x] #adds 3 to the values of the letters turned to number this also works
y=str([3+ ord(c) for c in x])  # this does not do what I expected it to do. Neither does char
print(y)

'''def decrypt (x):
y=str([-3 + ord(c) for c in x])
print(y)
'''


x=str(input("Enter something to be encrypted: ")) #gets string to encrypted

encrypt (x) #calls function sends the entered sentence

'''
x=str(input("Enter something to be decrypted: ")) #gets string to decrypted

decrypt (x)

'''
```

I commented out the second part of turning it back, if I can get it to give me back the string with the letters changed, I can probably figure the rest out.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str`, applied to a list of integers, as you discovered, gives you a string like `[65, 66, 67]`, not `ABC`. To convert a single integer back to a string, you can use `chr`. Then, to do it for a whole list of integers, use `join`:

```
y = ''.join(chr(3 + ord(c)) for c in x)
```